# How do I show $ |x|^{p}$ for $0<p<1$ is quasiconvex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics

Background (Quasiconvex defn):

A function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a convex subset $S$ of a real vector space is quasiconvex if for all $x, y \in S$ and $\lambda \in[0,1]$ we have
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y) \leq \max \{f(x), f(y)\}$$

Now I'm interested in showing this for

$ |x|^{p}$ for $0<p<1$ , $S = \mathbb{R}$

It is essentially [Wikipedia's image of a quasiconvex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function#/media/File:Quasiconvex_function.png)

I can see how it is true by looking at the graph, If I draw any line from two points on the graph, one of the ends of the line will be greater than the rest of the line.

Now I don't know how to proove this, essentially prooving$$
|\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y|^{p} \leq \max \{|x|^{p}, |y|^{p}\}$$.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is monotonous decreasing up-to $0$ and increasing from $0$.

Comment: @user251257 , Thanks, I can see how that proves it when x,y are both positive or both negative. And if x,y are one of each then the curve has to be below the line in between the points, so the max wil be either side. I don't know how to write this rigorously or as an actual proof

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is rigorous enough or correct.

But using the hint, I think it prooves it for any function that satisfies the hint.

For any $f: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we know $\mathbb{R}$ is convex set. If f is monotonically increasing in $[0,\inf)$ and decreasing in (-inf,0].

Then for any two points x,y

Either x,y are both positive or both negative than monotonicity is just the same as below but one side.

Or one is positive one is negative.

W.L.O.G Then if x $\in (-\inf,0]$ and y $\in [0,\inf) $then for$ z \in (x,y) $

$z \in (x,0] $

f(x) > ... f(z)  .. ≥f(0)

$z\in [0,y)$

f(0) ≤.. f(z) <... f(y).

Therefore  max f(z) st. z $\in [x,y]$ is either f(x) or f(y), and is greater than any
f(z) = (+(1−)) $0<\lambda<1$.

Proof that f satisifies the hint in the case of interest,
we can use the derivative: $$df/dx = p*x*|x|^{p-2}$$ 0<p<1, negative for negative x, positive for positve x

Comment: well what happens at $z\in [x, y] f(x) > ... f(0) f(0) < ... f(y)$? Just discuss both cases $z < 0$ and $z \ge 0$.

Comment: Right, so do you think this shows it?

Comment: it depends on what you write. It goes in the right direction

Comment: Ok thanks I think I've changed it to show what you suggest. Do you think that any fn which satisfies your hint, is quasiconvex. As this proof works for any such function right?

Comment: $z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$ for a suitable $\lambda$. Your derivative is wonky.

Comment: yes, a function $f$ with that property (decreasing up-to a point and increasing from that point on) is quasiconvex, but not vice versa. $-f$ is called unimodular. In some field, also $f$ is called unimodular

Comment: Ok thanks, Think my derivative is right, just a way to write sign(x). I don't know how to prove it writing z as a comb like that. but in 1-D that just means for every$ z \in [x,y]$ right?

Comment: the derivative does not exists at $x=0$. Also your formula breaks at $x=0$. I would exclude $x=0$. You still can conclude that $-f$ is unimodular.